# using angular-ui-route to inject a navrbar but the collapse button appears on my navbar even if the browser is full scaled

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using *angular-ui-route* to inject a navbar but the collapse button appears on my navbar even if the browser is full scaled. It appears properly on mobiles but not when my browser is full scaled.

[navbar web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWpKS.jpg)

[navrbar mobile browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNG6Y.jpg)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: how can i make it disappear on the web browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a media query to hide the `.navbar-toggle` element

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i have two navbar-toggle in one page and i only want one to appear on both mobile and web browser

Comment: Add an additional class to the one you want to disappear like `.mobile-only-toggle` and in the media query above, swap out the class `.navbar-toggle` for the `.mobile-only-toggle`.